# Correctly typing prop injection

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to inject a prop into a component. I had thought this would work, and having looked at it and tried multiple configurations, nothing seems to make the type check pass. Looking at other answers, I'm guessing I'm doing something stupid; but I can't see what.

I'm attempting to inject in the `alerter` prop in the example below, but I get the error:

> (parameter) WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType Type '{ alerter:
> (s: string) => void; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "alerter">>' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode;
> }'.   Type '{ alerter: (s: string) => void; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof
> T, "alerter">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> '{ alerter: (s: string) => void; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "alerter">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T'
> could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
> 'IWithAlert'.ts(2322)

I've seen the "but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" multiple times and fixed it before, but here, I can't see why it's even happening in the first place.

Any suggestions?

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface IWithAlert {
  alerter: (s: string) => void;
}

const withAlerter = <T extends IWithAlert = IWithAlert>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>
): React.ComponentType<Omit<T, "alerter">> => {
  return class WithVisibilityControls extends React.Component<Omit<T, "alerter">> {
    alerter = (s: string) => {
      window.alert(s);
    };

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent alerter={this.alerter} {...(this.props as Omit<T, "alerter">)} />;
    }
  };
};

const Test: React.FC<{ alerter: (s: string) => void; m: string }> = (props) => {
  return <button onClick={() => props.alerter(props.m)}>Click</button>;
};

const TestInjected = withAlerter(Test);

export default () => <TestInjected m="Hello" />;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a universal solution to props injection:

```
import { ElementType } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

////////
// Universal utilities
////////
export type ExtractComponentProps<
  T extends ElementType
> = T extends ElementType<infer P> ? P : never;
// Alias for breivity
type EP<T extends ElementType> = ExtractComponentProps<T>;

export function specializeComponent<
  T extends ElementType,
  K extends keyof EP<T>
>(Component: T, props: Pick<EP<T>, K>): ElementType<Omit<EP<T>, K>> {
  return function SpecializedComponent(innerProps: Omit<EP<T>, K>) {
    // Typecasting is justified because Pick<EP<T>, K> & Omit<EP<T>, K> = EP<T>
    const all = { ...innerProps, ...props } as EP<T>;

    return <Component {...all} />;
  };
}

////////
// Usage example
////////
type Alerter = (s: string) => void;

function Test({ alerter, m }: { alerter: Alerter; m: string }) {
  return <button onClick={() => alerter(m)}>Click</button>;
}

const TestWithAlerter = specializeComponent(Test, {
  alerter: (s: string) => window.alert(s)
});

export default function App() {
  return <TestWithAlerter m="foo" />;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67383159-5bipe?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way without type assertion `as`.

```js
import React, { FC } from "react";

type IWithAlert = { alerter: (s: string) => void; m: string }


const withAlerter = <Props extends IWithAlert, T extends Props>(
    WrappedComponent: FC<Props>
) => {
    const alerter = (s: string) => {
        window.alert(s);
    };

    const Foo: FC<Omit<T, 'alerter'>> = (props) => {
        const prop = {
            ...props,
            alerter
        } as unknown as Props

        return <WrappedComponent {...prop} />;
    }

    return Foo
};

const Test: React.FC<IWithAlert> = (props) => {
    return <button onClick={() => props.alerter(props.m)}>Click</button>;
};

const TestInjected = withAlerter(Test);

const x = <TestInjected m="Hello" />;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcARFKhrQNwBQrMAnmEnAJIB1YDAAWAQQA2SWHAC8uOCimxpALjgAKAM7qtMKMAB2AcwCUcgHxwAbhGAATZnBC79R46Xas0EQ3rgA7sLiyjDScnAAPAAKVGBacEgAHmGG9gmCwZLSWHAAKokpSGkJsRDxFhqscDVwAlAoYDz2hNSQhsUw6kQxcVoWrOayVjjVtT5%208Eo54fLargYmQyNjtbVBaRABAHTTsNqmbGskbKtwE-74EBDdhJEA8iDCkXnYAOR7YVBvFlZzYH1lrgzmsLvAAeUIqM1jDatt4RD4pgQbDFKFpCiamQUAkAK6GADWhi2hkUpT67FRcAYMFxUFJkXqjWarXAvk6uHh20RZAA9BYjrUSJTajS6aSrhBWCd2GD8kg9OpkOgYNseplRNlYH9NIitEDoaKkLT6VEAEa4mAwXxwXyECTANAE2Q4DRAvW7dFQDQekCmEgWe2OgmRXkWq2%20AXS05yvIKmB8QwAKyQGCQ9giQU1Xo0cb0h1lvn8SQiL3jiZTaYzIFktAAEkgJBIILQ4PzmEA)